# CSS: How can I put multiple pieces of content in a box/border?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to put a box around each vendor, deal pair in the following loop.

```
<% micropost.comments.each do |comment| %>

      <p4>
        <b>Vendor:</b>
        <%= comment.commenter %><br>
        <b>Deal:</b>
        <%= comment.body %>
      </p4>

    <% end %>
```

so that it has a box around all of [vendor:"vendor".  Then under that on a new line, deal:"deal"]

so in my css file I put

```
p4 {
  border-style:solid;
  border-width:3px;
}
```

also the entire thing is supposed to be indented so I have,

```
#blah_form input, textarea, b4 {margin-left:80px}
```

right now it just puts vendor in a half box kind of like a [ then returns down one line and puts deal with a half box ] around it.

Comment: What are p4 and b4? That's not valid HTML!

Comment: whoops it should be p4. Ill change it

Comment: I don't think `<p4>` is valid either?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use non-inline elements to achieve the effect you're looking for.
Replace (or wrap) `<p4>` in `<div>`

New code:

```
<% micropost.comments.each do |comment| %>

  <div class="box">
    <b>Vendor:</b>
    <%= comment.commenter %><br>
    <b>Deal:</b>
    <%= comment.body %>
  </div>

<% end %>
```

And CSS:

```
div.box {
    border: 3px solid black;
}
```